# Popen() blocks the process sometimes (usually under CPU load)

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, popen

I am simulating a traffic generator for a computer network (for my test each computer is a linux namespace). Each computer has a server (written in python) running and listening for commands. It can either spawn a TCP sender (using Sockets) or a TCP receiver (using netcat). Before starting each sender I send a command to the receiver's server so it spawns the TCP receiver before the sender starts sending data.

In order to handle the processes and kill them if necessary I use `Popen` to spawn the netcat process every time I need a TCP listener. I do as follows:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["nc", "-l", port], stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"))
processes_TCPServers.append(process)
```

First I create the process, and then I store all of them in a list to clean everything when needed.

**Problem**

Let's say I have only 16 hosts. When I start a considerable number of flows in a few seconds, some host's servers get blocked at the `Popen` call, while others do not.

However, if I use `os.system()` instead:

```
os.system("nc -l -p {0} >/dev/null 2>&1 &".format(port))
```

All the TCP listeners get spawn and nothing gets blocked. Even if I start 6K flows in few seconds.

**Observations**

I tried using the option `shell=True` and the problem remains.

Some people told me that it could be that I am hitting the maximum file descriptor limit per process. But I do not think so, I just start (if nothing gets blocked) 20 processes per process. And my limit its 50K `fd`.

What else can I try? I would like to use `Popen` since I can terminate the process in a elegant way, something I can not do with `os.system()`.

Comment: The two commands are not equivalent.  In `os.system` you append `&` which tells the shell to run the program in the background.  In `Popen` you do not do that, and would have to use `shell=True` if you did.

Comment: By default `Popen` is non blocking. So you do not need to use `&`. Yo could make `Popen` blocking by doing: `Popen().wait()` but is not the case. And as I said in the question it gets blocked sometimes (only when I stress the program a bit).

Comment: For netcat, why not use sockets directly?

Comment: @inf that would solve it I guess, but somehow, even the simplest python program uses 3% more of CPU, and I am running a big amount of processes 3% per flow is a lot.

Comment: @edgarcosta Makes sense, however I doubt that using sockets in python directly uses more CPU than spawning a process and then doing extra work. In terms of CPU usage, using PyPy might help.

Comment: @inf I thought the same, my first approach was using sockets, but even writing the simplest receiver the CPU usage was bigger than netcat. Any ideas regarding the `Popen` problem ?  It would be nice to know why os.system works and Popen does not (sometimes).